# Making predictions on new data with TensorFlow model that learned on x (inputs) from datasets that read input files, without reading input files

Tags: python, tensorflow

Can you pass the x -- aka the inputs aka independent variables -- using placeholder?  But there is no placeholder for x in the graph, by design. That's because this model was trained getting x by using dataset to read from text files, not placeholders.  Is this model now required to use input files for new data predictions due to prior training on input files?

Now a related but different question for the same such model: When making such predictions on new data on this model, are hyperparameter placeholders going to be required to be supplied explicitly?  If so what is the point of that?  The placeholders in this particular trained model's graph were used only for hyperparameters. (Training worked great this way, and I have run evaluations on the training and dev datasets.)  By my thinking, hyperparameters are only referenced during training which is when the cost is being computed and the optimizer operation is being evaluated.  As a reminder, I am only desiring to be evaluating the prediction (yhat), and I am not training now, I am not supplying the label y, the cost is not being computed using the hyperparameters in the cost expression, and the optimizer operation is not running.

Thanks if you know. (If you not sure of your answer please state that.)

Answer (score 0):

If the code has been written properly and the model has been saved properly (i.e only the actual layer weights have been stored !!!), this is not hard to achieve.

As I am not in office, I cannot test it out, but I am pretty sure that this is line in which you need to proceed. I have done something like this before.

You can use a function as follows :

```
def select_input(is_training=True):
    mode_variable = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.bool)
    if is_training:
        <Your dataset API logic goes here>
        def get_data():
            return <Iterator you created>.get_next()
    else:
        <Create a placeholder for your data you want to read>

    output = tf.cond(tf.equal(mode_variable, tf.constant(True)), lambda : get_data(), <Placeholder used>)
    return output
```